# Coinciding centroids of two triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I recently came up with a question.
Consider $\triangle ABC$. How many distinct triangles $\triangle DEF$ are there such that

1. Centroid of $\triangle DEF$ coincides with that $\triangle ABC$
2. Each side of $\triangle ABC$ contains exactly one of the three points $D, E$ and $F$

I know as a property that the [medial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle#:%7E:text=The%20medial%20triangle%20or%20midpoint,a%20polygon%20with%20n%20sides.&text=Each%20side%20of%20the%20medial,a%20midsegment%20(or%20midline).) of $\triangle ABC$ is one such triangle satisfying the two conditions.

However, is it the only triangle having such a property or, are there more (possibly infinite) such triangles?

Here's how I started off, let $D, E$ and $F$ lie on sides $a, b$ and $c$ respectively. Now divide $a$ in the ratio $m : 1$, $b$ in the ratio $n : 1$ and $c$ in the ratio, $p : 1$. The points $D, E$ and $F$ must satisfy the equation of sides $a, b$ and $c$, and using the ratios, their coordinates can be obtained.

From here, I'm unable to come to a conclusion.
It would be appreciated if someone could help me with the proof or give some kind of hint.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: let $d = \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$, $e=\mu b+(1-\mu)c$, $f = \nu c + (1- \nu)a$ with $\lambda,\mu,\nu \in [0,1]$, then triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ have the same centroid iff $a+b+c=d+e+f$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Those are the vertices in my notation (complex numbers, position vectors etc). The comment was meant as a hint towards $\,\lambda=\mu=\nu\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. Now I understand. I think important to specify you work with complex numbers (which is usual for us but maybe not for the OP).

Comment: @JeanMarie Right, thanks. That was too elliptic, though I'll leave the comment on, now that it's clarified.

Comment: @dxiv I have found (using the searching tool approach0.xyz) the same question [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h371919p2051309) with different answers, among them the shortest being yours, with complex numbers. There is also a nice purely geometrical proof.

Comment: @JeanMarie Nice find! I encourage the OP to peruse your link and post a self-answer with the solution that suits their context best.

Comment: A related question is the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952043/how-to-prove-two-triangles-have-the-same-centroid) generalization: if similar triangles $AYC, BZA, CXB$ are built on the sides of $\triangle ABC$ then triangles $ABC$ and $XYZ$ have the same centroid (and if $Y,Z$ are fixed then $X$ is the unique point with this property). OP's problem is the limit case where the exterior triangles degenerate to segments on each side.

Comment: @dxiv very nice indeed.

Comment: @dxiv You might be interested by this recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309085/geometric-center-of-points-located-on-a-regular-polygon/4309101) and its answer(s) extending the present question in another direction (to a regular n-gon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: Infinite such triangles exist when we divide all sides in equal ratios. More specifically when:
$\frac{BD}{DC} = \frac{CE}{EA} = \frac{AF}{FB}$

**Proof:**
Let side $A = (x_1, y_1)$, $B = (x_2, y_2)$, and $C = (x_3, y_3)$.
Centroid of $\triangle ABC = G$

$G_x = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3}$

Now divide these sides in the ratio m : 1. Solving this using section formula gives

$D_x = \frac{m x_3 + x_2}{m + 1}$

$E_x = \frac{m x_1 + x_3}{m + 1}$

$F_x = \frac{m x_2 + x_1}{m + 1}$

Centroid of $\triangle DEF = G'$

$G'_x = \frac{m (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) + x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3 (m + 1)}$

$G'_x = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3}$

Solving similarly for y coordinates, we can show that G' coincides with G, thus completing the proof.